# How to extend private tslint that are stored in github repo?

Tags: tslint

I am trying to extend a custom github repo installed via:

```
// package.json
"my-custom-rule": "mikebarron/custom-rules#custom-branch"
```

how to apply this rule in extends?

```
extends: ["mikebarron/custom-rules"]
```

just giving "custom-rules" wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the solution, looks like I needed to follow the "main" on "package.json" file, need to have "custom-rules" in this case.